# Asignar valor a variables globales desde ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

tengo una variables globales en mi "document ready":

```
var load_var_tiempor_s;
var load_var_tiempo_arr;
var load_var_preguntas_limite;
var load_var_range;
```

Estas variables son algunos tiempos y privilegios establecidos desde la base de datos, por lo tanto necesito cargarlos desde ajax, el problema es que ajax si trae el valor de vuelta y asigna el valor a la variable, pero solo dentro de la función en donde llamo a ajax, si las quiero utilizar fuera no me trae ningún valor, aparecen "indefinidas".

Ejemplo de mi código:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    /*Variables globales*/
    var load_var_tiempor_s;
    var load_var_tiempo_arr;
    var load_var_preguntas_limite;
    var load_var_range;

    if($('#vecontent').length ){
        loadConfig();
    }


    /*Funcion que pretende cargar el valor de las variables desde ajax*/
    function loadConfig(){
        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append("getconfigve", true);
        $.ajax({
            url:"../../views/ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data:datos,
            cache:false,
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#loading").removeClass('d-none');
            },
            success: function(regreso){
                $("#loading").addClass('d-none');

                load_var_tiempor_s = regreso['respuestatiempo'];
                load_var_tiempo_arr = regreso['timepor'];
                load_var_preguntas_limite = regreso['preguntaslimite'];
                load_var_range =  regreso['range'];

                /*Aquí todo es felicidad*/
                console.log(regreso);
                console.log(load_var_tiempor_s);
                console.log(load_var_tiempo_arr);
                console.log(load_var_preguntas_limite);
                console.log(load_var_range);

            }
        });
    }

       function mifunction1(){
           var tiempo =  load_var_tiempo_arr;  
           alert(tiempo);//Aparece undefinido
       }

       function mifunction2(){
           var preguntas =  load_var_preguntas_limite;  
           alert(preguntas);//Aparece undefinido
       }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Las funciones las tienes que definir por fuera del `ready()`, este solo aplica cuando necesitas inicilizar algo al terminar la carga de la pagina, como si fuera el load del form.

Aplica esto

```
/*Variables globales*/
var load_var_tiempor_s;
var load_var_tiempo_arr;
var load_var_preguntas_limite;
var load_var_range;

$(document).ready(function() { 

    if($('#vecontent').length ){
        loadConfig();
    }

}); 


function loadConfig(){
    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("getconfigve", true);
    $.ajax({
        url:"../../views/ajax.php",
        method:"POST",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data:datos,
        cache:false,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#loading").removeClass('d-none');
        },
        success: function(regreso){
            $("#loading").addClass('d-none');

            load_var_tiempor_s = regreso['respuestatiempo'];
            load_var_tiempo_arr = regreso['timepor'];
            load_var_preguntas_limite = regreso['preguntaslimite'];
            load_var_range =  regreso['range'];

            /*Aquí todo es felicidad*/
            console.log(regreso);
            console.log(load_var_tiempor_s);
            console.log(load_var_tiempo_arr);
            console.log(load_var_preguntas_limite);
            console.log(load_var_range);

        }
    });
}

function mifunction1(){
    var tiempo =  load_var_tiempo_arr;  
    alert(tiempo);//Aparece undefinido
}

function mifunction2(){
    var preguntas =  load_var_preguntas_limite;  
    alert(preguntas);//Aparece undefinido
}
```

como veras solo el if y la llamada a `loadConfig()` estan en el `ready()` el resto va por fuera